# Upload database in cpanel

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I had created database, table and some entries to the table in localhost ie. phpmyadmin
Now I want to upload my database so my website works properly online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually cPanel has a link to your phpMyAdmin account on the server:

[image]

There you can manage the database as you are currently doing in local.

You should also export (MySQL Dump or from PHPMyAdmin) your database layout from local, and then using the PHPMyAdmin shown, import the SQL to create the database.